# Why is $\{(3 y, y)\mid\; y \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}$ not a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Task:  Decide whether the following subsets of Cartesian products can be understood as functions between the specified sets.
I took a online test in Analysis and I marked this as as a function but the site said I was wrong without further explanation. Why is that not a function?

Comment: Your MathJax is messed up...

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What's $f(1){}$?

Comment: yes I meant $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is a function, just not a function from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. The domain is $3\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common definition of  " function from $\;\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\;$" implies that the function's defined on the whole $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

If we also assume the usual agreement that the first entry in each pair is from the domain and the second one is the image of that entry , then the set of pairs you're given cannot be defined on $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , since the first entry (i.e., what should be in the definition domain) cannot be $\;1\;$ ...or in fact, any other element in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ which is not a multiple of $\;3\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

A function needs to map every element of its domain to a member of its codomain. For any $x$ not a multiple of $3$, there is no $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is in your given set, so...

Comment: Thank you I should definitely read through my calculus books.